# How can i save media files (images, audios, etc...) to NativeScript application?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

so yeah guys, i just started learning NativeScript and i'm making test projects, i tried to make app, that plays little audio file when you touch button, but i don't know how to save files in the program, (i know, i'm 0 to explaining stuff with English) so i can use them later...

i haven't tried any plugin yet, so if there's any about my problem, i will be glad to hear about it

yeah, there's way to store them in servers or cloud, but i'm trying to make offline application...